# Need to edit "Continue Shopping" button to include page refresh

Tags: cart

Right now we have a popup set up when somebody clicks "add to cart" that displays the products, addon sales etc. and a "Continue to Checkout" or "Continue Shopping" button.
The problem is when somebody clicks "continue shopping", the minicart doesn't update and shows nothing in cart until the page is refreshed.
So I'd like to change the "Continue Shopping" button to include an automatic page refresh - any help on exactly how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, a refresh can be done via `location.reload();`

Answer (score 2):

add this on the "Continue shopping" button.

```
onclick="window.location.reload()"
```